# How to download another private repository in Github Actions with Cargo?

Tags: github, rust, github-actions, rust-cargo

**Problem**

I have a private Rust project (A) and it depends on another private Rust project (B). On my local machine, it works because I am logged into git. I am not sure how to login into git in Github Actions. I am not sure if it's needed. I am reading so many things about SSH and HTTPS, that I lost track of what I must do.

I saw https://github.com/webfactory/ssh-agent, https://github.com/fusion-engineering/setup-git-credentials and a few other actions, but I am just guessing things I need to do and I can not get it to work.

**Setup**

This is my Cargo.toml file on in project A:

```
...
[dependencies]
b = { git = "https://github.com/me/b.git" }
```

This fails in Github Actions because Github Actions can not download the private repository without some token. I created a personal access token and changed my Cargo.toml to this:

```
...
[dependencies]
b = { git = "https://ignore:MyPersonalAccessToken@github.com/me/b" }
```

but I get an email from Github that my token is revoked because it isn't allowed to have it hardcoded in the code...

Now I am not sure what to do. I can put the token in my github secret, but I don't know how my cargo.toml can use that.

Is there an easy way to just login into git in Github Actions? I tried https://github.com/OleksiyRudenko/gha-git-credentials and configured my workflow like this:

```
- uses: oleksiyrudenko/gha-git-credentials@v2-latest
  with:
    token: '${{ secrets.GIT_CREDENTIALS }}'
    global: true
```

But cloning still fails:

> Caused by:   failed to authenticate when downloading repository
>
> - attempted to find username/password via git's `credential.helper`
>   support, but failed

I tried also the library https://github.com/marketplace/actions/setup-git-credentials, but I guess I am mis using it

**Question**

How can I make Cargo clone private git repositories with Github Actions?

Comment: Why not using the `actions/checkout` or another action to clone the repo on the github action workflow. Is it not compatible?

Comment: That would maybe work, but than I have a cloned repo on the Github worker. How would my cargo.toml file look like? I don't want to refer to local paths

Comment: I guess the cargo.toml file would have to refer to the runner local paths to work. Therefore that doesn't seem to be an option in your case :/

Comment: @GuiFalourd Nah, it's an ugly workaround... than for each and every (future) private repo, I need to clone it, locally AND on the CI worker :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can add this [action](https://github.com/webfactory/ssh-agent) after your checkout step and GitHub can access your private repo dependancy.

Note:- Make sure to add a server's private key as a secret, public key to GitHub SSH keys and Please replace your private repo URL from https+auth_token to SSH.
`ssh://git@github.com/your_group/your_project.git`

Comment: Note: don't forget to set the env property in the workflow (descriped in the readme of the action)

Answer (score 5):

An easiest way to solve this problem is using the git `url.insteadOf` feature.

First of all, create a `.cargo/config.toml` file in your project root and add this (this force cargo to use git cli instead of libgit2):

```
# .cargo/config.toml
[net]
git-fetch-with-cli = true
```

Now, assuming that you have created a personal access token and added it to the (for example) `GIT_CREDENTIALS` repository environment variable:

```
# Cargo.toml
[dependencies]
b = { git = "https://github.com/me/b.git" }
```

You can do this inside your CI before any cargo command:

```
# my_action.yaml
git config --global url."https://${{ secrets.GIT_CREDENTIALS }}@github.com".insteadOf https://github.com
```

*OR:*

Alternatively, commonly is better for the developer to use ssh instead of https to fetch git dependencies. In this case, you can do:

```
# Cargo.toml
[dependencies]
b = { git = "ssh://git@github.com/me/b.git" }
```

In CI will be:

```
# my_action.yaml
git config --global url."https://${{ secrets.GIT_CREDENTIALS }}@github.com".insteadOf ssh://git@github.com
```

This will override the url adding the token and allowing you to fetch the dependencies using https. **Reminder**: don't forget the `git-fetch-with-cli = true` configuration.